# CakePHP router only work for '/' not other, why?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp. In my cake project, I can't route to other directory.

```
Router::connect ('/', controller => 'home', action => 'index')
```

work properly. But not others. I have (eg. `'/view/page', controller => 'view', action => 'page'`) not working:

> error - directory not found.

Appreciate to any comment and suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: are you made view controller ?

Comment: I use cakephp 2.6.0.

Comment: I use controll and view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is I didn't configured mod-read-write in my server apache config file (.htaccess).
It should be
'AllowOverride All' in both server base dir and web root dir.